# Как в TChart-е получить область за пределами графика(вне осей и тд)

Tags: delphi, teechart

Как узнать в `OnClick` чарта кликнули ли мы за пределами области с собственно графиком? Т.е. область внутри чёрных рамок (границы TChart) и вне красных.

[image]

Comment: Сам нашёл ответ  - у чарта есть метод CalcClickedPart, который позволяет заполнить структуру, в которой есть поле с типом того, куда мы кликнули - на легенду, на заголовок, на ChartRect и тд.

Comment: Оформите самоответ с минимальным кодом. По чарту не так много полезной информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  LClickedPart: TChartClickedPart;
begin    
  CalcClickedPart(X, Y, LClickedPart);
  if (LClickedPart.Part <> cpChartRect) then
    ...
end;
```

Кроме области, из структуры `TChartClickedPart` можно узнать какая точка и сериес по указанным координатам.

Answer (score 0):

Если "область собственно графика" ограничена осями, то можно сравнивать X-координату с

```
Chart1.BottomAxis.IStartPos
Chart1.BottomAxis.IEndPos
```

И аналогично для Y и LeftAxis

Comment: Нет, это так не работает, к сожалению=_=

Comment: Как именно не работает? Для обычных серий нормально работает.